# Enriching the response array with the corresponding elements in the request array

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Input request :

```
[
    {
        "id" : "1",     
        "make" : "NAHB"
    },
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "make" : "Honda"
    },
    {
        "id" : "3",
        "make" : "Samsung"
    }
]
```

I am using iterate, to send each element of above array as request to a backend service( In myactual project this is not so simple service i.e. its reponse is very complex with lots of arrays and sub-arrays(child arrays)in it . for better understanding of issue I kept it like this ).

The responses of the backend service are aggregated in one soap xml by AggregateMediator.

Below is response from AggregateMediator

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Information>
            <jsonObject>
                <id>3</id>
                <name>Mobile</name>
                <model>S8</model>
            </jsonObject>
            <jsonObject>
                <id>2</id>          
                <name>Car</name>
                <model>Amaze</model>
            </jsonObject>
            <jsonObject>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Home</name>
                <area>5000sqft</area>
            </jsonObject>
        </Information>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to enrich above response from AggregateMediator like below using input request.
i.e. I want to merge input request and output of backend service.(id is common between them.)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Information>
            <jsonObject>
                <id>3</id>
                <name>Mobile</name>
                <model>S8</model>
                <make>Samsung</make>
            </jsonObject>
            <jsonObject>
                <id>2</id>          
                <name>Car</name>
                <model>Amaze</model>
                <make>Honda</make>
            </jsonObject>
            <jsonObject>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Home</name>
                <area>5000sqft</area>
                <make>NAHB</make>
            </jsonObject>
        </Information>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I kept input request array in a property before calling backend services and was able to access it in response flow.
but the problem is "both request and response are arrays". How could I run two foreach on two different arrays simultaneously and also match their id before updating each array element of response.

foreachTest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/foreschTest" name="foreachTest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/hi">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="//jsonArray" name="message"/>
            </log>
            <property expression="//jsonArray" name="req" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <foreach expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement" id="Loop">
                <sequence>
                    <property expression="get-property('Loop_FOREACH_COUNTER')" name="countid" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <!-- <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" property="INCOMING_REQUEST" type="property"/>
                        <target type="body"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <id xmlns="">Y</id>
                        </source>
                        <target action="sibling" xpath="//jsonElement"/>
                    </enrich>  -->
                    <!--<enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="property" property="INCOMING_REQUEST"></source>
                        <target action="replace" type="body"></target>
                    </enrich>   -->
                    <!-- Temporily commented   <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <uniqueId xmlns="">Y</uniqueId>
                        </source>
                        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonElement/data[2]"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" property="countid" type="property"/>
                        <target xpath="//jsonElement/data[2]/uniqueId"/>
                    </enrich>  -->
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="get-property('countid')" name="mgs7"/>
                    </log>
                    <log description="" level="custom">
                        <property expression="get-property('Loop_FOREACH_ORIGINAL_MESSAGE')" name="mgs5"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('Loop_FOREACH_COUNTER')" name="mgs6"/>
                        <property expression="//jsonElement" name="msg8"/>
                    </log>
                    <log description="" level="custom">
                        <property expression="//jsonElement/data[0]" name="msg9"/>
                        <property expression="//jsonElement/data[1]" name="msg10"/>
                        <property expression="//jsonElement/data[2]" name="msg11"/>
                    </log>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <iterate expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement" id="1">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <log level="custom">
                            <property name="msg2" value="&quot;Inside iterate&quot;"/>
                        </log>
                        <log level="full"/>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint key="modifyAgrRespEP"/>
                        </send>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="info" scope="default">
                <Information xmlns=""/>
            </property>
            <aggregate id="1">
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="info" expression="//jsonObject">
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property name="msg3" value="&quot;Inside Aggr&quot;"/>
                    </log>
                    <log level="full"/>
                    <foreach expression="//Information/jsonObject">
                        <sequence>
                            <log level="custom">
                                <property name="msg4" value="&quot;Inside Foreach&quot;"/>
                            </log>
                            <property expression="$body" name="agr" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                            <log level="custom">
                                <property expression="get-property('agr')" name="agr"/>
                            </log>
                            <!--    <log level="full"/>  -->
                        </sequence>
                    </foreach>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

modifyAgrRes.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/mod" name="modifyAgrRes" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/aggr">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="&quot;Inside Modify Service *************************&quot;"/>
            </log>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="//jsonObject" name="location"/>
            </log>
            <switch source="//jsonObject/id">
                <case regex="1">
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <name xmlns="">Home</name>
                        </source>
                        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <area xmlns="">5000sqft</area>
                        </source>
                        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                    </enrich>
                </case>
                <case regex="2">
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <name xmlns="">Car</name>
                        </source>
                        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <model xmlns="">Amaze</model>
                        </source>
                        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                    </enrich>
                </case>
                <case regex="3">
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <name xmlns="">Mobile</name>
                        </source>
                        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" type="inline">
                            <model xmlns="">S8</model>
                        </source>
                        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                    </enrich>
                </case>
                <default/>
            </switch>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="//jsonObject" name="msg20"/>
            </log>
            <enrich>
                <source clone="true" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                <target type="body"/>
             </enrich>
            <log level="full"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a high-level answer; I guess you can work the details out for yourself:

1. Copy the input ($body) to a new property (inputBody) at the
   beginning
2. Transform $ctx:inputBody to XML - see this URL for an example:
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT
3. Do all intermediate processing steps
4. Loop through the $ctx:inputBody property, and for each row,
5. Get the /id (currentId) and /make (currentMake) into new properties
6. Use the Enrich mediator to add a child
   /Information/jsonObject[id=$ctx:currentId]/make with value set to
   $ctx:currentMake
7. Convert back to JSON if necessary.

I hope that helps.